# Redirecting to a div with post data

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I am searching a table for specific values based on the user input which queries the database for the LIKE condition. This works perfectly but I have to manually scroll to the buttom of the page to see my filtered table. I really want to redirect the user to the div of the table underneath the page. This is the form with the search box:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right" style="margin-right:130px; width:30%;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Alerts for Today...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" name="searchnow" type="submit" value="Submit">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This code below then checks to see if the button is clicked and then sets the variable that populates the table to equals the current search result from the database.

```
    var searchIP = "";
    if (Request.Form["searchnow"] != null & IsPost)
    {
        searchIP = Request.Form["search"];
        alertForTheDay = dbConnection.searchDashboardTable(searchIP);
        // Response.Redirect("Dashboard.cshtml#search");
    }
```

Using Response.Redirect refreshes the table back to its original state. Commenting out the Response redirect as shown above allows the filter to be possible but I have to manually scroll down the page. I want this to redirect to the id of the div in that redirect. Please what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing a complete server round trip. From my point of view this is unnecessary. 
I would suggest to do this via AJAX.

1. Change the HTML like this to call an AJAX operation on your button click:

   ```
   <form method="post">
       <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right" style="margin-right:130px; width:30%;">
           <div class="input-group">
               <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Alerts for Today...">
               <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-default" name="searchnow" id="theButton">Go!</button>
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. Handle the button click and link to your anchor on success. (Assuming that the anchor to your table is present. In your case something like `Dashboard.cshtml#contact`)

   ```
   $.fn.gotoAnchor = function(anchor) {
       location.href = this.selector;
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
       // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
       $("#theButton").click(function() {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<YOUR URL>",
               data: { search: $('#search').val() },
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(msg) {
                   // If everything is successful link to your anchor tag
                   $('#search').gotoAnchor();
               }
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Hello Daniel thanks for the answer. I have just edited the redirect in the question as they was a typo. changed it from 'Response.Redirect("Dashboard.cshtml#contact");' to 'Response.Redirect("Dashboard.cshtml#search");' because thats the name of the id of the div I want to redirect to. I have changed the anchor tag to search instead of contact and the URL to 'Dashboard.cshtml' but this filters the table fine but does not redirect to the div

Comment: Did you check my HTML? I have added a `id="search"`

Comment: Yes I copied your HTML. It does not still redirect to the div but it does filter the table

Comment: sorry. Success handler should be like `$('#search').gotoAnchor();` i have updated the answer

Comment: I have corrected that in my code previously but still did'nt work.